# For an application using Log4J (not SLF4J) how to swap the underlying implementation for something we are developing internally?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

So I have a large application using log4j. We are developing internally our own log implementation, that has nothing to do with log4j, but it conforms to the log4j API for logging. Therefore we just want to somehow swap log4j for our log implementation without changing anything in our code, in other words, it will continue to use the log4j API with our log implementation under-the-hood.

Has anyone done that or know how to go about doing that?

It would be easy if I was using SLF4J, but unfortunately I'm not.

Comment: You've developed a custom appender or an entire logger class?

Comment: @aribeiro entire logger class, an entire logging framework

Comment: Have you tried looking at `log4j` documentation? You have both the [Extending](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html) and [Programmatic Configuration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html) docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to write your custom logging framework as an slf4j implementation.

Then, remove log4j from the class path and drop in the log4j-over-slf4j bridge instead.
http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html

The log4j-over-slf4j bridge will take any calls made to log4j and redirect through slf4j to whichever slf4j subsystem you're using on your classpath, which would in this case be your custom library.